# C++ dynamically linked library not found in executable

Tags: c++, c, gcc, shared-libraries, rpath

I have a `.so` in the path `/home/test/lib/libTest.so` and an executable called `myexec` that is built with `RPATH` pointing to `/home/test/lib/`. However, when I did `ldd` on `myexec`, it says `libTest.so` not found and I had to do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in order for it to work.

I have confirmed:

1. `libTest.so` does exist in `/home/test/lib/`
2. `objdump -x myexec | grep RUNPATH` does indicate `/home/test/lib/` is built into the executable.

Does anyone have idea why it couldn't find the library without setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed,

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html):

> In Linux, the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated set of directories where libraries should be searched for first, before the standard set of directories

As a tip, you should be careful not to replace entirely your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It could mess up the path for the system shared libraries.
Always use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/your/path`.

**EDIT 1:**

As for the `rpath`, make sure that `libTest.so` doesn't depend on any other library. As an alternative you can use `-rpath-link` option in gcc instead of `-rpath`, as seen [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html):

> -rpath-link DIR
>
> When using ELF or SunOS, one shared library may require another. This happens when an ld -shared link includes a shared library as one of the input files. When the linker encounters such a dependency when doing a non-shared, non-relocateable link, it will automatically try to locate the required shared library and include it in the link, if it is not included explicitly. In such a case, the -rpath-link option specifies the first set of directories to search.

**EDIT 2:**

If you want more help, please provide:

1. Exact parameter for `rpath` used during compile
2. Output for `ldd /path/to/binary` command
3. Output for `readelf -d /path/to/binary`

Comment: Does this actually address the question? OP asked why  an external environment variable (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) was necessary when the required path was already built into the executable.

Comment: I admit the answer was not satisfactory. I just edited it requesting more information. Sorry about that.